# Liquibase PostgreSQL sequence re-generation

Tags: spring, hibernate, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I migrated Liquibase from version 3 to 4.5 and Liquibase re-generates all existing sequences.

I have the following changeset in my main changelog

```
<changeSet author="radouane (generated)" id="1619214415688-1">
    <createSequence incrementBy="1" sequenceName="actor_business_entity_id_seq" startValue="1"/>
</changeSet>
```

When starting my app, the sequence is correctly created in my database

[image: sequence in the database]

But when i run a liquibase diff with my jpa model a new changeset is present in the diff for the sequence.

Comment: If you run a `liquibase diff` what does Liquibase list as differences? That can help with understanding why liquibase wants to create the sequences.

Comment: it lists table, columns, constraints, primary keys... and every thing except sequences.

Example :
[INFO] Found column id int8
[INFO] Found table street
[INFO] Found primary key streetPK
[INFO] Found column id int8
[INFO] Found column country varchar(255)
[INFO] Found column wording varchar(255)
[INFO] Found column id int8
[INFO] Found table user_account
[INFO] Found unique constraint UK_agx9n4ffugbl0ls8ln3qtpvp on user_account(preference_id)
...